# Temp files not deleted?

Tags: jboss, jna, jboss6.x, temporary-files, delete-file

We are using JBoss 6, the jna tmp files are created but not deleted.

path:

```
jboss.server.home.dir/tmp
```

files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root         182908 Mar  5 14:43 jna1000075621423330119.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root         182908 Mar 13 21:21 jna1000448379897914340.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root         182908 Mar  8 00:53 jna100087558889160466.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root         182908 Mar  5 17:53 jna1001389809425363375.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root         182908 Mar  6 23:14 jna1001847722792022649.tmp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root          root         182908 Mar  9 09:19 jna1002218205957676424.tmp
...
```

Comment: On non-windows systems, these are ordinarily deleted when the com.sun.jna.Native class's class loader is disposed.  On windows systems, you cannot delete them from within the VM but they get marked for deletion the next time JNA loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears than some app or library uses [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/README.md) to call native code. 
Those `jna*.tmp` files are actually some `lib*.so` native libraries unpacked to current temp dir.
JBoss itself doesn't use native code.
You can try to identify who actually uses JNA. But the easiest approach would be just to add tmp dir cleanup to jboss startup script.